# How to store terraform state in one account and apply changes in another account using AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I have set up an AWS Organization using ControlTower. I created a user for myself that has AWSAdministratorAccess for the 2 accounts below.

- Root

  - Operations Group (Organizational Unit)

    - Infrastructure Account (AWS Account - 111)
  - Dev (Organizational Unit)

    - DEV Account (AWS Account - 222)

I am starting simple for now to get a good base foundation while building up the organization. One thing I have read is that we should be storing our terraform state files in the Infrastructure Account while doing our operation changes on the DEV Account.

How can I do that in terraform? I am a bit lost because I am using AWS SSO and can't figure out what to place for the role_policy_arn.

Here is an example code:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "terraform-infrastructure"
    key    = "dev/sqs/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-1"
    assume_role_policy_arns = ["<what do I put here>"]
  }

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.16"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.2.0"
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  allowed_account_ids = ["222"]
}
```

Also, is there anything I need to do on the S3 side? I am assuming **no**. If I can assume the role of AWSAdministratorAccess for Infrastructure Account and store the terraform state there and assume the role of AWSAdministratorAccess for DEV Account and apply my changes, then I don't need to mess with S3 permission to allow cross account publications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider adding the [`profile` configuration](https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/s3#profile) to the `backend` block. The associated profile will need to be setup in your `~/.aws/config` file. Also, you can add the [`profile` configuration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#profile) to the `provider` block to similarly use the AWS CLI profiles. Using the `profile` configurations and setting up [AWS CLI using profiles with correct accounts and roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html) should enable you to accomplish what your intending to do.

Comment: That should work! The only thing I was worried about was that all future developers need to match the way I set up the profile configuration.

Comment: Maybe that is not a problem? Is that common?

Comment: Consider using a setup shell script to configure non secret parts in a common way across workstations.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Terraform documentation, you should be using an IAM role delegation:

> - Each role's Assume Role Policy must grant access to the administrative AWS account, which creates a trust relationship with
>   the administrative AWS account so that its users may assume the role.
> - The users or groups within the administrative account must also have a policy that creates the converse relationship, allowing these users
>   or groups to assume that role.

AWS IAM credentials should allow access to both the S3 backend and to Terraform's AWS provider.

```
variable "workspace_iam_roles" {
  default = {
    staging    = "arn:aws:iam::STAGING-ACCOUNT-ID:role/Terraform"
    production = "arn:aws:iam::PRODUCTION-ACCOUNT-ID:role/Terraform"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  # No credentials explicitly set here because they come from either the
  # environment or the global credentials file.

  assume_role = {
    role_arn = "${var.workspace_iam_roles[terraform.workspace]}"
  }
}
```

References:

- https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/s3#delegating-access